# JavaScript ES6 - Static method in parent class returns value set in child

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, static

I have this class structure:

```
class Component{
    constructor(name){
        this.__name = name;
    }

    static getName() { return this.__name; }
}   

class ComponentChild extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super("myName");
    }
}
```

When I call

```
console.log(ComponentChild.getName);
```

I would expect `myName`

Instead I get `undefined`.

Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: `__name` is not a static member of the class. So you won't get it anyway. Besides, `getName` is a function, you're not calling it anywhere.

Comment: infact you are trying to access `getName()` as a property getter function but it's not like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OOP static properties and functions belong to the class they are declared into, hence they do not have access to instance properties or functions, so you would need to make that function non-static.

```
getName() { return this.__name; }
```

*Further explanation*

You must take into consideration that JS is not a class-based but a prototype-based OOP language, before ES6 declaring a "static" function was done as a property of the constructor function:

```
function Component(name) {
     // ctor logic
}

Component.getName = function(){ 
     // fn logic 
}
```

So inside a "static" function your *this* is the constructor function.

**Update**

If you **must** use a static method you could write an accessor function like

```
class Component {
    static getName(instance) {
        return instance._name;
    }
}
```

And then use it as

```
console.log(Component.getName(instance));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` in a static function to refer to an instance. Static functions are static because you invoke them on the class itself, not an instance; thus, they have no access to instance members.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: Is it an answer? It is not solving the problem anyway; you could have posted a comment instead.